# visualizarImg() is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onchange

Tags: javascript, html5, upload

Já vi alguns tópicos parecidos com esse, segui as recomendações e não tive sucesso, por isso abro novo tópico. 
Esse erro ocorre quando eu faço o upload de uma imagem e na hora de exibi-la aparece essa mensagem. 
PS: Já verifiquei as importações da página e está tudo ok.

HTML

```
                                <div class="form-group col-md-12" >
                                     <div class="form-group">
                                      <input type="file" id="file" onchange="visualizarImg();" />

                                      </div>
                                </div>
                                   <div class=" form-group col-md-6">
                                      <img id="imagemPromocao" src=""  class="img-responsive"  />   
                                   </div>
                                </div>
```

JavaScript

```
window.onload = function() {
    function visualizarImg() {
        var preview = document.querySelectorAll('img').item(1);
        var file = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onloadend = function() {
            preview.src = reader.result;// carrega em base64 a img
        };

        if (file) {
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        } else {
            preview.src = "";
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como a função está dentro do onload, ela não pode ser acessada pelo html. Ou você coloca ela fora do onload ou adiciona um evento dentro do onload ao inves do evento no html:

```
seuinput.addEventListener("input", function () {
    //aqui o código da função visualizarImg
}, false);
```

Comment: Se eu colocar fora do onload eu terei o seguinte erro : `Cannot set property 'src' of null at FileReader.reader.onloadend`

Comment: Entao deixa a funcao dentro do onload e adiciona o evento tambem dentro do onload.